# Two factor authentication with ssh.net

Tags: c#, two-factor-authentication, ssh.net

I am trying to connect from a Windows app to a unix server, to run some commands (automating checks on server status).  I am using the ssh.net library, and have this code to connect to the server:

```
using (SshClient ssh = new SshClient("myserver.univ.edu", "myusername", "My!maginaryPa55wrd"))
{
    ssh.Connect();
    var result = ssh.RunCommand("df -h");
    LogText.Text = result.Result;  // puts result of command into multiline textbox
    ssh.Disconnect();
}
```

But when I run this, it times out on the connect.  I am guessing this is because the server requires two factor authentication.  When I log into it with Putty, it will prompt for username and password, it then prompts for a choice of factors ... `enter a passcode or "1" for Duo push to xxx-xxx-1212 or "2" for phone call to xxx-xxx-1212`.

The SSH.net library says it supports two-factor authentication, but I have searched all over for a way to do it, and I am coming up empty.  Any clues as to how to solve this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a restricted account on the system for this? That would be better than 2 factoring, since it's an automated check

Comment: @Jaxi - Yes, not a possibility with the myriad of systems that will be checked.  But thanks!  It was a good thought.

Comment: The timeout was not because of the 2FA.  It was because I misspelled the server name.  Once I got it right, the connect went through fine.  In a little while I will delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have two factor authentication, you have single factor and a bunch of interactive options, which is non-standard and not supported by ssh.net. It's not expecting to have to make choices.

To make this work, you would need to modify the ssh.Net code, or better, setup Public Key Authentication with the remote servers, in which case it won't need a password or 2FA.

Any reasonable size organization almost certainly has PKI setup. You would need to check with the admins and see about getting your Public Key added to the servers you'll be checking.

ssh.Net supports public key auth and would eliminate all the problems you're having.

Comment: This is not correct.  2FA will, in some systems, prompt the user to choose how to use the second factor - i.e. username and password = first factor (something you know); your phone = second factor (something you have); do you want a push, a text, or a call to that phone?  This is perfectly well within the standards.

Comment: NIST SP 800 63 b lays out the standards for multi-factor authentication.  Is there another?  Nothing I read in it precludes giving the user a choice of how the physical authenticator or OTP device, being used as a second factor, is to be used.  I suppose I could be wrong, but I would need to be shown a standard that prohibits giving the user a choice.

Comment: My understanding is that when a standard does not include something but does not prohibit it either, it is up to the implementation to do as desired.  The standard presents multiple ways that a physical authenticator/OTP device can be used.  Why not give the user a choice on which one they want?  This has saved my skin before.  When i had to replace my phone and had not set up the 2FA software on it yet and had an emergency at work, that server also gave me a choice and I was able to tell it to just use a voice call to my phone to verify.

Comment: I am the OP.  And yes, it is supported.  If you look at my comment on my original question, I misspelled the server name which caused the timeout.  Once I spelled it right, SSH.NET was able to connect just fine.